# How I can measure the path in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I used a path object in Anylogic. I want to measure the length of it. 
I want to know how can I use length() method to measure the length.

I tried to write:
double length (path)
but it shows me there is an error!

Anyone Could help me with that?

Comment: If you have a `Path` object, the `.length()` method gives you the length in the unit you specify. 

Please read how to ask good questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ) as "It did not work" is really not helpful at all ;-)

Comment: Ok. Could you show me how to use .length() method? please

Answer (score 0):

See [this example model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/udb5ijpjfv9qunb/Model12.alp?dl=0), not sure what your problem was...